# Pthread segmentation fault

Tags: c++

The following code has written in c++ to run an odd-even sort with two threads. I received a segmentation error at the execution. I tried with gdb with break points at line 55, 57 and 62. But the segmentation error jumped after those break points. Can't figure out where the error is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

#define num 2

pthread_mutex_t mutex1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

using namespace std;

nt arr[]={10,9,23,45,78,11,89,45,92,5,23,76,34,21,59,76};

void* odd_even(void* data){
int a=*((int*)data);
int temp;
bool sorted=false;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
while(!sorted){
   if(a==0){
    sorted=true;
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr)-1;i+=2){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
            sorted=false;
        }
    }
   }
   else if(a==1){
    sorted=true;
    for(int i=1;i<sizeof(arr)-1;i+=2){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
            sorted=false;
        }
    }
   }
}//end while
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
//pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){

//int arr[]={10,9,23,45,78,11,89,45,92,5,23,76,34,21,59,76};
nt a[]={0,1,2};
int thread_id;
thread_t pth[num];
pthread_t dthread;

for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
   thread_id=pthread_create(&pth[i],NULL,odd_even,(void*)&a[i]);
   if(thread_id){
       cout<<"Thread creation fail"<<endl;
       return 0;
   }        
}
for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
  pthread_join(pth[j],NULL);

pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not going to get any performance benefit from threading if the function simply claims the mutex for its entire lifetime. This effectively serialises the threads so you may as well do it in one.

Comment: Can you indent the code properly?

Comment: in the for loop:
`i<sizeof(arr)-1`
should be `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` or even better `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: @paxdiablo: I agree. I just thought to add the mutex to the the swapping area in both for loops. So if it is swapping it will lock other wise both threads are able to check the elements in array. Thanks. Ignore the previous one

Comment: @n.m.: my intention is distinguish two threads so that they will work with odds and evens separately.

Comment: I have just modified my code to add the mutex to the swapping section in the loops. Now I don't get a segmentation error. But the program seems stuck. Does that means it occurs a race condition.

Comment: @user3237370 Sorry, I've misread the code. The real reason is that you are not using `sizeof` correctly, just as @GuyL says in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code,

- Calculating the length of the array should be done as `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`
- Striding for *odd* and *even* should increment the index by 2 instead of 1

Have a go with something like this:

```
void* odd_even(void* data)
{
    int a=*((int*)data);
    volatile bool sorted=false;
    unsigned int arr_length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    while(!sorted) {
        if (a==0) {
            sorted=true;
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < arr_length-2; i+=2) {
                if(arr[i] > arr[i+2]){
                    std::swap(arr[i], arr[i+2]);
                    sorted=false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (a==1) {
            sorted=true;
            for(unsigned int i=1; i < arr_length-2; i+=2){
                if(arr[i] > arr[i+2]){
                    std::swap(arr[i], arr[i+2]);
                    sorted=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }//end while
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return nullptr;
}
```

**EDIT. [See live.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/337c28a1ce2a0e54)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added this with my main function. Now no segmentation errors. But the output is not sorted. I think the issue is with the comparison since odd even sort compare consecutive cells in array by means of odd columns and even columns. Anyway this answer to my question since I had trouble with segmentation error. I'll try to figure out where is the error in my code. Thanks for the help...

Comment: The code (if I understood your intention correctly) is supposed to sort the even stride and the odd stride separately, if you look at the output you'll see that the evens and the odds are sorted. You'll need an additional step to merge the result.